# redirect domains and subfolder to new domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns, subdirectory

I have 4 domain which I want 3 of them redirect to last one. I already used some htaccess rules and they are working great,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^first.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.forth.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.first.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.forth.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^second.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.forth.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.second.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.forth.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.third.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.forth.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^third.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.forth.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

the only problem is when I enter "www.first.com/about" it does not shows "www.forth.com/about" just shows the same thing . all the domain are forwarded to forth.com and they do not have hosting so I cannot put htaccess file for those other domains , please guide. would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify one thing, when you say 'the only problem' is that it doesn't show the new domain - do you mean it doesn't work at all and doesn't redirect? Or you mean it does redirect and just doesn't change the hostname in the browser url field? Also, is "first" the only one that doesn't work or they all have the same behavior?

Comment: Yes it does redirect but on the browser address bar , shows the old address , and it is only when the url comes with a subfolder , if I type the URL itself it will redirect and change name too. and all the three domains do the same behavior with subfolder, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely what is happening, at least on my test cases this fix handles it.

Instead of using [L,R=301] reverse the order and do [R=301,L]. The L means Last and it ends cycle on evaluating what to do at that point. I've always used [R=301,L] as are all the examples that I could find anywhere. Potentially your apache may be hitting that L and immediately pass back the new string to the URL parser and isn't sending it as a 301 Redirect as it didn't get that far.

Also on the first.com snippit above you left out the $ on the ^(.*) - only for that line though, not sure if this was a typo or if it's missing in your actual .htaccess file.

Otherwise, you could tidy it up a bit by using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)first.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)second.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)third.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.forth.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks peter , But first the OR at the end totally block my website, and after I remove OR , it act same as before , I did change the location of L and nothing change in practice. and the $ was a typo .

Comment: Totally correct on the last OR, editing the above to fix. I can do some more testing, but that should work.

Comment: I set up a local environment with a fresh apache install and copied the above as the `.htaccess`, put in 127.0.0.1 for first.com, second.com and third.com in my `/etc/hosts` file, then used www.google.com for the redirect site. It works with and without specifying a file or just domain name and does change the URL in the browser. The only added step is ensure that in your `httpd.conf` that you set the `AllowOverride` correctly. I used All for my test, by default it's None and won't work that way.